# Add series total to legend in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using Highcharts.js - I want to add the series total to the legend (where it currently says '12345'). I know enough that I need to write a labelFormatter function, but I don't know enough JavaScript to figure out how to sum up the total of each series. Code is below (also live version here: http://jsbin.com/ukabob/8).

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            backgroundColor: '#E9E7DC',
            borderRadius:0,
          margin: [0, 150, 30, 0]
        },
        colors: ['#A74B59', '#46C4B7', '#EDBA70'],
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },          
        title: {
            text: null
        },            
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018',
                '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022'],                
            gridLineWidth:1,
            gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
            labels: {
              style: {
                color: '#000000'
              },
              formatter: function() {
                return '<div style="font-size:22px; font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif;">'+
                    this.value +'</div>';
              },
              y:25
            },
            lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
            tickColor: '#FFFFFF',
            tickLength: 30
        },
        yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth:0,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
              enabled: false
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            marker: {
                radius: 6,

                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: null, // inherit from series
                symbol: 'circle',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fillColor: '#E9E7DC',
                        lineWidth: 2,
                      radius:6
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
              hover: {
                lineWidth:4
              }
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
            borderWidth:0,
            borderRadius: 0
            },
        legend: {
          borderRadius:0,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            itemMarginBottom: 7,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',                
            y: 30,
            x: 2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            width:130,
            symbolPadding: 10,
            useHTML:true,
            shadow: {
              color: '#000',
              width: 3,
              opacity: 0.15,
              offsetY: 2,
              offsetX: 1
            },
            labelFormatter: function() {
              return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:16px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">(Total: 12345)</span>';
        }

        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Honeywell',
            data: [700,725,750,850,950,1000,1025,1050,1050,1050]
        }, {
            name: 'Bombardier',
            data: [661,758,880,990,1065,1136,1193,1241,1289,1335]
        }, {
            name: 'Embraer',
            data: [747,789,839,861,890,908,984,1030,1097,1156]
        }]
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 12):

A more generic & dynamic answer:

```
legend: {
   labelFormatter: function() {
      var total = 0;
      for(var i=this.yData.length; i--;) { total += this.yData[i]; };
      return this.name + '- Total: ' + total;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out.  I added the total to the series, then called it with this.options.  See updated code below:

```
        legend: {
          borderRadius:0,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            itemMarginBottom: 7,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',                
            y: 30,
            x: 2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            width:130,
            symbolPadding: 10,
            useHTML:true,
            shadow: {
              color: '#000',
              width: 3,
              opacity: 0.15,
              offsetY: 2,
              offsetX: 1
            },
            labelFormatter: function() {
              return '<div class="' + this.name + '-arrow"></div><span style="font-family: \'Advent Pro\', sans-serif; font-size:16px">' + this.name +'</span><br/><span style="font-size:10px; color:#ababaa">(Total: ' + this.options.total + ')</span>';
        }

        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Honeywell',
            total: 9150,
            data: [700,725,750,850,950,1000,1025,1050,1050,1050]
        }, {
            name: 'Bombardier',
            total: 10548,
            data: [661,758,880,990,1065,1136,1193,1241,1289,1335]
        }, {
            name: 'Embraer',
            total: 9301,
            data: [747,789,839,861,890,908,984,1030,1097,1156]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I was surprised that this work for me. HighChart didn't provide any documentation on this