# What are the attributes that can be used in Highcharts' legend.labelFormat property?

Tags: highcharts

I'm playing around with the properties of a chart I created in Highcharts, and I'd like to know what attributes are associated with the `legend.labelFormat` property. I know that `{name}` is one that definitely works, but I can't find documentation regarding any other attributes that can be used.

I suppose that I'm looking for something similar to the `tooltip.pointFormat` property, where you can use attributes like `{point.value}`, `{point.percentage}`, and so on.

What makes me think that additional properties other than `{name}` exist is [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754823/add-series-total-to-legend-in-highcharts) in which the user mentions using `this.options.total` in the `legend.labelFormatter` property.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other attributes that can be used are attributes of a series. You can check what are defined attributes of a series using browser console (Developer Tools) and labelFormatter function.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e7w88usj/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        legend: {
            //labelFormat: '{color} {index} {symbol}',
            labelFormatter: function () {
                console.log(this);
                return this.name;
            }
            // (!) labelFormat will override labelFormatter if both are used
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 9, 8]
        }, {
            data: [1, 2, 34]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Why I can't use for example dataMax? it shows in console.log(this), but this.dataMax returns undefined
http://jsfiddle.net/Ly8f7chw/

Comment: @rluts Open browser console, run this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4h1qfjwb/), make sure it stops at the `debugger` that I have added, check the `this` then - no dataMax. This is because at the time of the console log you don't have dataMax calculated yet, but if you are opening the object in the console after the chart has finished all the initial rendering then the object is evaluated at that time of the object being opened - this is a general JS/console way of working. In Chrome, you could see a small icon with a tooltip "Value below was evaluated just now.".