# Highchart show percentage on group column highcharts

Tags: css, highcharts

[image: Image description]
`Code Link` : http://jsfiddle.net/SpzBa/18/

I have problem with show percent column in highchart for group colunm. I have 1 group column highchart. I need show all percent and sum of each column as 
red circle crossed

Comment: You have mistakes in your code and that is the reason why your stackLabels was not working. Here you can see an example of working stackLabels: http://jsfiddle.net/SpzBa/22/

Answer (score 0):

[links](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yra1rw51/)

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yra1rw51/

    .legend-title {
    display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    margin:1px 10px;
    padding:0 5px;
}
.legend-value {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:rgba(204,204,204,.25);
    margin:1px 10px;
    padding:0 5px;
    font-weight:normal;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks you but not i want. I have problem with Datalabel in highchart.

Comment: Okay I am trying give me some time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754823/add-series-total-to-legend-in-highcharts